# Getting the value of textbox and using it as a filename in PHP

Tags: php, html

I am trying to get the value of a textbox and use it as the filename for the file that will be downloaded. But I don't know how to do that.

So far my code does download but I cannot use the value of the textbox as its filename. So here's my code, and what should I add to be able to get the value from the textbox and use it as the filename of the downloaded file?

Here's the HTML side:

```
//HTML Code:
<form method="post" action = "/downloads.php">
    <table width="100%" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td width="49%" height="47"> <span class="new">  &nbsp; Reference Number: </span> </td>
            <td width="51%" height="47"> <span class="nbox"> &nbsp; <input type="text" name="refOff" id="refOff"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="47" colspan="2">&nbsp;<input type="submit" value="Download" style="width:80px; height:30px"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

And here is the PHP

```
//PHP Code: 
//note: "C:\wamp\www\dl" contains the PDF file

<?php

$refOff = $_POST['refOff'];
$file   = $refOff . '.pdf';


if (file_exists($file)) {
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
readfile($file);
exit;
}
?>
```

The file that is being downloaded is "Form2.pdf".

For example, the reference number is abcd123, how can it be downloaded as "abcd123.pdf"? Thank you, for being nice ^_^

Comment: It would help if your code actually used the form value. Do you need help on how to handle forms?

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the filename set in form and then set it.

Just update your php code to this:

```
$file   = 'C:\wamp\www\dl\Form2.pdf';
$filename = (isset($_POST['refOff'])) ? $_POST['refOff'].'.pdf' : 'form2.pdf'; //Get filename set in form

if (file_exists($file)) {
  header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
  header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename); //Set the filename
  header('Expires: 0');
  header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
  header('Pragma: public');
  header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
  readfile($file);
  exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: i did try and there is no file being downloaded. why is that so?

Comment: try error_reporting to on and see if there are some errors

Comment: sorry, i am not that good in PHP, i dont know how to do that =(

Comment: thank you, I did and it says: Notice: Undefined index: refOff

Comment: are you sure you came to download page by submitting the form you showed in the html ?

Comment: before i changed the code to look like the one you have suggested, I can download the file, but the filename is Form2.pdf

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57258/discussion-between-syed-qarib-and-ladywinter).

Answer (score 1):

You can access form variables by their respective supervariable ($_GET and $_POST).
So first you should define a method in your form

```
<form method="GET">
```

Then you can access a variable of that form in this way:

```
$_GET['name']
```

Replace name with the attribute name of the input you want; in your case

```
$_GET['refOff']
```

The same thing is valid for POST method.

---

Also, the way specified by the other user isn't wrong. But avoid not defining a form's method. And avoid relying on `$_REQUEST`, it can lead to many security issues if used without experience.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
```

by

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($_REQUEST['refOff']));
```

Comment: i did try but no file is being downloaded